# Groupby without using underscore js

Tags: javascript, jquery, grouping

I have a collection which is group by ID. Each id contains array of objects. I want to loop through it and create a target collection which will be group by "Id" column as shown on the example. I will not use underscore js. I have to use javascript reduce method to achieve this.

```js
var targetCollection = [{
    123456: [
        { "Id": "1", "name": "xxx", "age": "22" },
        { "Id": "1", "name": "yyy", "age": "15" },
        { "Id": "5", "name": "zzz", "age": "59" }
    ],
    789456: [
        { "Id": "1", "name": "xxx", "age": "22" },
        { "Id": "1", "name": "yyy", "age": "15" },
        { "Id": "5", "name": "zzz", "age": "59" }
    ]
}]

var targetOutput = [{
    123456: {
        1: [{ "Id": "1", "name": "xxx", "age": "22" }, { "Id": "1", "name": "yyy", "age": "15" }],
        5: [{ "Id": "5", "name": "zzz", "age": "59" }]
    },
    789456: {
        1: [{ "Id": "1", "name": "xxx", "age": "22" }, { "Id": "1", "name": "yyy", "age": "15" }],
        5: [{ "Id": "5", "name": "zzz", "age": "59" }]
    }
}]
```

```js
Code Snippet I have tried which didn't work

var newArray = [];
$.each(targetCollection, function (key, value) {
    var newTarget = $(this);
    var targetCollectionNew = newTarget.reduce(function (result, current) {
        result[current.ParentAreaID] = result[current.ParentAreaID] || [];
        result[current.ParentAreaID].push(current);
        return result;
    }, {});

    newArray.push(targetCollectionNew);
});

console.log('newArray', newArray);
```

I have tried with array reduce method and it didn't work. Please help me.

Comment: The solution is easy enough, but what have you tried so far? Where is the code that doesn't work?

Comment: It would be great if you can let me know the solution. I have tried so many things and now its not undoing to the position you are asking for.

Comment: It shouldn't be too hard to post your latest code. Otherwise you have simply posted a problem set.

Comment: ok, I have updated what I had tried with.

Comment: Post your latest code, even if it's a mess. What is blocking you? Break it down into the steps that you need to do.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem with your original attempt is that you need to have two loops because in the first one `newValue` is an object not an array, so there is no `reduce` method on it.

The simpler solution is to use map (you could use `forEach` or `$.each`) and reduce in the second loop (I used simple `for-in`).

Something like this:

```js
var targetCollection = [{
    123456: [
        { "Id": "1", "name": "xxx", "age": "22" },
        { "Id": "1", "name": "yyy", "age": "15" },
        { "Id": "5", "name": "zzz", "age": "59" }
    ],
    789456: [
        { "Id": "1", "name": "xxx", "age": "22" },
        { "Id": "1", "name": "yyy", "age": "15" },
        { "Id": "5", "name": "zzz", "age": "59" }
    ]
}];

var result = targetCollection.map(function(obj) {
    for (var key in obj) {
        obj[key] = obj[key].reduce(function(prev, curr) {
            if (!prev[curr.Id]) prev[curr.Id] = [];
            prev[curr.Id].push(curr);
            return prev;
        }, {});
    }
    return obj;
});

document.write('<pre>' + JSON.stringify(result, null, 4) + '</pre>');
```

Comment: hey! you know what you are a champ!!!. This works perfect and thanks for explaining what wrong on this. This really helps.

Comment: This would modify the original object. See my answer as to why.

Comment: @JasonCust Yes I know, however I seems to me that this not a problem (maybe this is response from the server that needs to be restructured). In most cases I would expect object to be still references after wrapper array is transformed. Btw, you solution is also passes object by reference.

Comment: @dfsq Only the inner object is passed by reference and it is noted in the comments of the code as well as how to avoid doing so.

Comment: @JasonCust In this line `idObj[el.Id].push(el);` el is also passes by reference.

Comment: @dsfq Exactly...hence the comment directly above it: *"This will pass by reference the internal objects, so you could use the prior technique to create a new object to avoid downstream modification"*. I didn't say your answer was wrong just warned about what is generally unexpected behavior for a lot of people. I left the second one in purposely to show that even at that level it can still occur but noted how to avoid it.

Answer (score 2):

You should compare your current object, `targetCollection`, and your desired output object, `targetOutput`, to plan the transformations you will need:

```
targetCollection: Array --> Object --> Array --> Object
targetObject: Array --> Object --> Object --> Array --> Object
```

You can see the outer Array will be a 1:1 mapping so there is no need to reduce here.

The next level is an Object but again it is a 1:1 mapping. However because JavaScript passes objects by reference you will need to create a new object to avoid modifying the original object. And since we are creating an object from another object we can leverage the power of Object.keys to create an array and then use Array.reduce to create an object from those keys.

The 3rd level is where we first encounter the real transformation of the structure from an Array to an Object. Again, we can use Array.reduce to aid this step.

So from this plan of attack you can see the flow should be `map --> reduce --> reduce`.

```js
var targetCollection = [{
  123456: [{
    "Id": "1",
    "name": "xxx",
    "age": "22"
  }, {
    "Id": "1",
    "name": "yyy",
    "age": "15"
  }, {
    "Id": "5",
    "name": "zzz",
    "age": "59"
  }],
  789456: [{
    "Id": "1",
    "name": "xxx",
    "age": "22"
  }, {
    "Id": "1",
    "name": "yyy",
    "age": "15"
  }, {
    "Id": "5",
    "name": "zzz",
    "age": "59"
  }]
}];

// 1:1 mapping
var targetOutput = targetCollection.map(function(obj) {
  // 1:1 mapping but we need to create a new object to
  //   avoid modifying the original object
  // Object.keys returns an array of keys (that are enumerable)
  //   and then reduce creates the new object
  return Object.keys(obj).reduce(function(newObj, key) {
    // The desired transformation takes place here
    newObj[key] = obj[key].reduce(function(idObj, el) {
      idObj[el.Id] = idObj[el.Id] || [];
      // This will pass by reference the internal objects
      //   so you could use the prior technique to create
      //   a new object to avoid downstream modification
      idObj[el.Id].push(el);

      return idObj;
    }, {});

    return newObj;
  }, {});
});

document.write('<h3>targetCollection</h3><pre>' + JSON.stringify(targetCollection, null, 4) + '</pre>');
document.write('<h3>targetOutput</h3><pre>' + JSON.stringify(targetOutput, null, 4) + '</pre>');
```